# OpenCL - Large Strings and Memory Performance?

Tags: opencl, bioinformatics

I'm an OpenCL newbie but I've had good success with many of the examples I've found online.  My application is very basic bioinformatics so I'm concerned with very long strings of "ACTCGAAAGGTA...." perhaps 1-3MB long.  A simple calculation would be to count the number of A,T,C,G elements and that seems very suited for OpenCL.  So if I start with the canonical "add two vectors" example found [here](http://opencl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OpenCL%20Tutorials%20-%201)

```
__kernel void vector_add_gpu (__global const float* src_a,
                     __global const float* src_b,
                     __global float* res,
               const int num)
{
   const int idx = get_global_id(0);
   if (idx < num)
      res[idx] = src_a[idx] + src_b[idx];
}
```

My question is, do I need to concern myself in any way with splitting up the original string among the work groups or work units?  I do understand the check for idx < num, so I get the concept that the work item "knows" whether it is in range or not.  Is it OpenCLs job to manage this for me?   Are there conditions where I do need to explicitly manage splitting my global data into chunks?   Perhaps if they exceed a certain size?  (probably dictated by my hardware limitations?)

I want to get my fundamental OpenCL concepts correct before I waste a ton of time :)

TL;DR:   Do I ever have to split up "large" strings of input data?   Or does OpenCL do all that magic for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access these arrays just like in pure C code, there's not necessarily any explicit need to partition the input arrays in any way.  If you access the array by the global thread id, it's going to be a unique index from the global work pool, which sort of handles the partitioning for you.

The thing to be careful about is making sure that you don't read past the end of your array since you may have to pad the final work group, but you seem to understand that part just fine.